# How to render data in a drop down using JQuery and Ajax in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using backbone and marionette for a web app, i'm trying to populate a drop down menu with some JSON after an option has been selection.

So the user selects their account type, an AJAX request is fired and the data is returned.

However i'm stuck at populating the relevant drop downs with the returned data.

This is my AJAX request which is triggered after a user selects an account:

```
   accountSelect: function () {

                var accountCode = $("select#accountcombo").val().toString();
                var jsonUrl = "webapp/json?accountCode=" + accountCode;
                $.ajax({
                    url: jsonUrl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        accountCode: $("select#accountcombo").val()
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            return
                            { 
                            states: _.pluck(data.states, 'state'),
                            products: _.pluck(data.products, 'product')  
                            };
                            $('#select#statecombo').selectpicker('render');
                            $('#select#productCombo').selectpicker('render');
                        //  this.render();
                    },

                });          

    }
```

So by looking at the console i see the request works, the data is returned, however its the `success:function` element which isn't working.  The drop downs which are populated by default on load work fine and not sure what i'm missing.

This is the HTML for the states which i'm trying to populate (held in a template):

```
    <div id ="states"><h2>States</h4>
    <% _.each(states, function(item){ %>
    <li value="<%= item %>"><%= item %></li>
    <% });%>
    </div>
```

The JSON is in the following format if this helps:

```
{
    "states": [
        {
            "state": "AL",
            "products": [
                {
                    "product": "phone",
                    "types": [
                        {
                            "type": "smarta1",
                            "typeRelease": [
                                2013,
                                2014
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
            ]
}
```

Comment: it might be best to show your code in jsfiddle. Also it's best to use the fetch() function to get the json objects instead of using $.ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i'v made mistake

Try

```
// get data from response
var states =  _.pluck(data.states, 'state');
var products =  _.pluck(data.products, 'product');
// create select inner html
var statesContent = _.map(states, function(val){ return '<option>'+val + '</option>';}).join();
var productsContent = _.map(products, function(val){ return '<option>'+val + '</option>';}).join();
// rerender select
$('select#statecombo').html(statesContent).selectpicker('render');
$('select#productCombo').html(productsContent).selectpicker('render');
```

Comment: Hey that worked, although i had to add:
`$('select#productCombo').selectpicker('refresh');`
To the end to have them show - but it's working now, thanks a million.  If i'm ever rich i'll erect a statue in your honour.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning in your `success` function before populating your drop down menu, try to change the order like this :

```
$('#select#statecombo').selectpicker('render');
$('#select#productCombo').selectpicker('render');

return
{ 
    states: _.pluck(data.states, 'state'),
    products: _.pluck(data.products, 'product')  
};
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that hasn't fixed it - the combo box is still empty.  Anything else i can try?

Answer (score 0):

At first you call $('#select#statecombo').selectpicker('render'); after **return** 
so this code won't execute

Also I can't understand what for you need return?

Try this code ( on success update selectpicker - you didn't it at your code and rerender it )

```
accountSelect: function () {

            var accountCode = $("select#accountcombo").val().toString();
            var jsonUrl = "webapp/json?accountCode=" + accountCode;
            $.ajax({
                url: jsonUrl,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    accountCode: $("select#accountcombo").val()
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                   $('select#statecombo').selectpicker('val', _.pluck(data.states, 'state'))
                                          .selectpicker('render');
                   $('select#productCombo').selectpicker('val', _.pluck(data.products, 'product'))
                                            .selectpicker('render');
                },

            });          

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work.  I didn't get any error but the drop downs are still blank.  
I used that return because that's what is used when the page initially starts up.  And those drop downs work so was trying to replicate it.  Populate the defaults and re-load it.  Anything else i could try?

Comment: can you publish link to your page? It will be better to check errors

Comment: ow, and what strange id $('#select#statecombo') ?? it's invalid, i think. It's my fault probably - fix to $('select#statecombo') and  $('select#productCombo')

Comment: Yes i changed those too but didn't solve it - i can't publish i'm afraid.
When i've tried the above with:
   `var stateoutput = _.pluck(data.states, 'state');
   var productoutput = _.pluck(data.products, 'product');`

and then logged these in console i get `[]`
So it doesnt look like it's being passed the data

Comment: Sorry, after Parsing it the data does appear when i do 'stateoutput' and 'productoutput' in the console.
So it's just a matter of getting this to the dropdown.  The data looks right.  So just don't know why it won't work.

Comment: I am confused with your phrase about ' then logged these in console i get []' cause if you get empty array - nothing to change simplepicker - and you'll see no changes as now

Comment: Yes i apologize i mis-spoke, i do not get an empty array - both my arrays contain data.